# How to know what dependencies where loaded by LoadLibrary?

Tags: c++, winapi, loadlibrary

Calling LoadLibrary will try to load the specified library and any dependencies (MSDN: "The specified module may cause other modules to be loaded.").

How can I get a list of the names (or even better, the module handles) of any dependencies that were loaded as a result of the LoadLibrary call?

Thanks!

Comment: Google "show loader snaps".

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am with @David on this one. The only reason to find out which modules were loaded, or attempted to be loaded is for diagnostic reasons. Asking for module handles sounds like the wrong approach to whatever goal you are after. Maybe you could explain what you're ultimately trying to achieve. Chances are that you will get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do it programmatically, you can:

1. make a list of loaded modules before calling `LoadLibrary` (e.g. with ToolHelp or PSAPI)
2. make the same list after calling `LoadLibrary`
3. compare the two and list the new ones

However, this will not catch the dependencies which were already present in the process (kernel32 etc).

Comment: Many thanks for all suggestions. I'm marking this response as the answer because I need to do this programmatically in code, not in a debug environment, which I think Hans' answer refers to (I should have been explicit about this in the question.).